# Prove by induction that $\sum_{j=1}^n 2^j = 2^{n+1} - 2$ for all $n\geq 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am having a seriously hard time figuring this question out once I get to the induction step. I end up getting here:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{(k+1)} 2^j = 2^{(k+1)+1} - 2$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{(k+1)} 2^j = 2^1 \cdot 2^{(k+1)}-2$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{(k+1)} 2^j = 2 \cdot 2^{(k+1)}-2$$
But I can't seem to get any further than this.

Comment: In your first line, you are assuming the statement you want to prove.  Instead, write $$ \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} 2^j = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^j + 2^{k+1}$$ and use the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see it's true for $n=2$. Assume it's true for $n$ (that is, our induction hypothesis is $\sum_{j=1}^{n} 2^{j} = 2^{n+1} - 2$), then

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} 2^{j} &= 2^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n} 2^{j}\\
&\stackrel{IH}{=}2^{n+1}+(2^{n+1}-2)\\
&=2\cdot 2^{n+1}-2\\
&=2^{n+2}-2\\
\end{align}

which completes the inductive step. Thus, it must be true for all $n$.

---

But let's look at what you did. You had this:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{(k+1)} 2^j = 2 \cdot 2^{(k+1)}-2$$

Which was really close! Simply subtract $2^{k+1}$ from both sides to obtain the induction hypothesis you did. Although you should work from the hypothesis, that is, the expression with $k$, *towards* the expression with $k+1$, and not the other way around, you only did reversible steps, so you could've just written your proof backwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! This cleared it up for me!